# Click() method does not return after clicking a link

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a Web Element (a link) that is correctly found on my page.

`<a onclick="javascript:doPostDMS('en-us'); return false;" id="btnPentana" title="Post To DMS" class="shelf-button lnkPostToDMS" href="javascript:__doPostBack('btnPentana','')"></a>`

The problem I have is when I execute the click, the button is clicked, a new browser window is opened (this tells me I did actually click), but the click method doesn't return and the test hangs.

With the following code:

`Console.WriteLine("Before");`

`element.Click();`

`Console.WriteLine("After");`

I see the Before statement written to the console.
I see the new window open (a result of clicking the link).
I do Not see the "After".

I'm using Selenium DotNet, 2.29.1
I've tried this using both the Chrome, and Firefox browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think to try is to add a time out feature for/to click and then catch the error.  I know click can have issues.